# Calling View from Class

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I think I have a simple issue with my app.
First of all I am using the PraseSDK in order to use the LoginView they offer.

Now I was going to create that function and let it called by a view controller in

`-(void) viewDidLoad`

It worked perfectly.

Now I was wondering if I can put that code into a global function class?

Well I created a Class called: `glo_function`
Inside of it I created a function which is call

```
+(void) CallLoginScreen{
PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
login.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton;
 [self presentModalViewController:login animated:NO];}
```

In My ViewController Iam using "callLoginScreen" like this

```
[glo_function CallLoginScreen]
```

The methode is going to be called by the View Controller but the view  will not show up.
Well I get that error will trying to run the app.

```
No known class method for selector 'presentModalViewController:animated:'
```

So I am pretty sure It do to the fact that I used the "self" in->

```
[self presentModalViewController:login animated:NO]
```

Can someone help me out with it? should be easy, hopefully :)

-----------------------Response------------------------------

Hi after I did that, the app crashes.
The Call methode looks like that:

```
    [glo_function showLoginScreenUsingViewController];
```

In glo_function.m the methode looks like that:

```
+ (void)showLoginScreenUsingViewController:(UIViewController *)VC {
PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
login.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton;
[VC presentModalViewController:login animated:NO];}
```

The Result when starting the App:

```
2012-12-28 21:20:24.003 Logbuch40[1942:c07] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
, reason: '+[glo_function showLoginScreenUsingViewController]: 
unrecognized selector sent to class 0x22e9ec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"self" always refers to the object you are in. In your case it's the glo_function object. So when you say self you are talking to the wrong object.

You could still do what you want but in your glo_function method you need to pass in a reference to your view controller. Then just use that in your function instead of self.

```
+ (void)showLoginScreenUsingViewController:(UIViewController *)VC {
     PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
     login.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton;
     [VC presentModalViewController:login animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: OK thats what I thought! Well I just need to know how to do that! :)

Comment: After I debuged a bit more I found out that the method is not called and the App crashes before entering the method showLoginScreenUsingViewController. So I think the problem is in Line:
[glo_function showLoginScreenUsingViewController];

Comment: Found my problem!
in my glo_function.h I forgot to change the method name.
After I did that I changed the call method to:
[GlobaleFunction showLoginScreenUsingViewController:self];

Thank you very much! :)
Problem solved! :)